# Azure AD Domain Services and LDAPS on a Sonicwall SMA appliance

Tags: sonicwall, entra-domain-services

I want to use LDAP authentication for SSL-VPN on a SonicWall SMA\SRA unit.

Endusers will then use their Azure AD username and password when connection to VPN.

Have enabled LDAPS with public CA wildcard certificate and opened port 636 for the WAN of the appliance.
Used the [guide here](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/configuring-active-directory-ldap-over-tls-certificate/170505251062387/) to setup LDAPS on the SonicWall but I am not able to connect.
The guide refers to a full SonicWall appliance so the menus are not exactly the same on the SMA unit but close enough I believe.

I can connect with LDP.exe.

Have anyone any experience connecting a SonicWall via LDAPS to AAD-DS? Any tips?

Comment: Hi, after adding the LDAP server, you are usually able to test the connection from the SMA, and the structure of your AD can be listed too from the SMA. Can you confirm you see something ? (like shown on that image; https://sonicwall.rightanswers.com/portal/app/portlets/results/onsitehypermedia/090170907330210.png?linkToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzb25pY3dhbGwiLCJleHAiOjE2MTAwMjIxNzIsImlhdCI6MTU3ODQ4NjE3Mn0.K_cKJBGZc0fYMa6cw2RzYsXztenTMYJcrSkLAyQhHzk)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to accept the settings on the SonicWall before you can test the connection. Works ok now :-)